# Apache SSL Proxy Pass not working, but it does with VirtualBox NAT port forwarding

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, virtualbox, proxypass

I configurated Apache proxy pass on port 80 and 443. Port 80 works but it seems that for 443 I do not get any response. From my public ip I got no response from server. This are the virtual host configuration I got in file `httpd-vhost.conf`

This works as expected

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.example.com

    SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://{LOCAL_IP}/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://{LOCAL_IP}/    
</VirtualHost>
```

This does not work.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN On    
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off

    SSLCertificateFile C:\{PATH_TO_CERTS}\cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\{PATH_TO_KEY}\key.pem
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / https://{LOCAL_IP}/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://{LOCAL_IP}/
</VirtualHost>
```

But for testing purposes, I set a VirtualBox environment NAT for port forwarding. And forward from local machine port 443 to virtual machine 443 port; and site does work in port 443.

Am I missing something I did not configure?

Comment: Is LOCAL_IP listening on port 443? What does the Apache error log show?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I found the problem, apache wasnt listening on port 443. I will a response to this question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The configuration was ok but I checked what ports were open and `LISTENING` - Apache was not listening on TCP Port 443 and the firewall was blocking connections on that port.

Added rule to firewall to open that port and I added a line in `httpd-vhost.conf` file at the beginning of the file

> listen 443

And the problem was solved. HTTPS over apache was loaded.